# Unable to find coordinates of a point on $\sin(x - k) + c$ graph.

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

For a)i) I have found the coordinates of $A$ by finding $x$ which is equal to $\frac{\frac{4\pi}{3}}{2} = \frac{2\pi}{3}$

To find $y$ I first find $k$ and then $c$ in the equation $\sin(x - k) + c$ and then use the fact that $1 + c = y$.

I get the right answer which is $A(\frac{2\pi}{3}, \frac{3}{2})$.

However the question uses the word hence in the part a)ii). This seems to imply that it is possible to find $A$ without finding $k$ or $c$.

If this is possible, how do you find $A$ without first finding $k$ or $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You already found the $x$ coordinate of $A$.

To find the $y$ coordinate, first draw a line parallel to the axis $Ox$ that "symmetrizes" the graph vertically.

You may find out geometrically that this line is precisely $(0,\sin(a))+Ox$, where $a$ is such that $2a+\pi=4\pi/3$. Then $a=\pi/6$ and the line is $(0,1/2)+Ox$.

Then, from that, you may find out that the $y$ coordinate of $A$ is $1+ 1/2$.